# js - get piece of string

Tags: javascript, string

I'm in a trouble with getting product version.

For example, I have 3 pieces of string:

string 1 : `version 2.1.3.1`

string 2 : `ver 21.3.4`

string 3 : `v 10.2.1`

How could I get number `2` in string 1, `21` in string 2 and `10` in string 3 with a single function?

Comment: Are they separate variables?

Comment: They are results returned from another function.

Comment: CHeck out my answer and the performance test

Comment: @Amit Joki: You got my concern. Your answer is awesome now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Regex isn't always bad

Use this:

```
function getMajorVersion(str){
    var matches = str.match(/\d+/); return matches && matches[0];
}
```

If you are worried about performance, use my answer instead of Allen Chak.

Here is jsperf: http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-native-in-simple-case

Comment: Except that if no match is found, it will return an error. Better to add a line of code to make it robust than worry about a few nanoseconds, e.g. `var matches = str.match(/\d+/); return matches && matches[0];` so that if no match is found, it returns *null*.

Comment: @RobG, are you talking in favor of Allen?

Comment: I'm suggesting how to make the function more robust. Allen's answer will return *undefined* if no "match" is found.

Comment: @RobG, thanks, I've included your code. But I don't how it works especially this part `&&`

Comment: It's saying *if match is falsy, return it, otherwise return match[0]*. the result of `str.match(...)` will either be *null* if no matches were found or an array. So the line returns *null* in the first case or the first member of the array in the second.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
function getMajorVersion(versionStr){
    var tmp = versionStr.split(' ');
    var v = tmp[1].split('.');
    return v[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getProductVersion(str) {
    return str.match(/\d+/g).map(function(v) { return parseInt(v, 10) });
}
```

Now you can use this to get the major version:

```
var version = getProductVersion('version 2.1.3.1');
var majorVersion = version[0];
```